# Reading asm cpuid directly

Tags: c++, assembly, driver, kmdf, cpuid

How I can read this instruction directly:

```
unsigned int eax, ebx, ecx, edx;
unsigned int leaf, subleaf;
unsigned int  intbuf[12];`
char *buffer;
int i,j,k,base,start,stop,length;
float freq_GHz;
float frequency;

subleaf=0;

base = 0;
for (leaf=0x80000002; leaf<0x80000005; leaf++) {
    
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("cpuid" : \
      "=a" (eax), "=b" (ebx), "=c" (ecx), "=d" (edx) : "a" (leaf), "c" (subleaf));


    intbuf[base] = eax;
    intbuf[base+1] = ebx;
    intbuf[base+2] = ecx;
    intbuf[base+3] = edx;
    base += 4;
}
```

I've been trying to read it like this but its not working:

```
for (leaf = 0x80000002; leaf < 0x80000005; leaf++) {
        
        int regs[4];
        __cpuid(regs, leaf);
        
        intbuf[base] = (*regs),eax;
            intbuf[base + 1] = (*regs),ebx;
            intbuf[base + 2] = (*regs),ecx;
            intbuf[base + 3] = (*regs),edx;
        base += 4;
```

Comment: What is e.g `(*regs),ebx` supposed to do? That's using the comma-expression, `*regs` (which is equal to `regs[0]`) is discarded and you only get the value of `ebx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `regs` array that you pass to the `__cpuid` call<sup>1</sup> will, on return, have the values of the four registers, `EAX`, `EBX`, `ECX` and `EDX`, in order (i.e. in the array elements, `regs[0]` thru `regs[3]`). You access those elements using *normal* array operators, and there is no need for any temporary 'register' variables like your `eax`.

Thus, your 'pure' C++ code would look something like this:

```cpp
int intbuf[12];
int base = 0;
for (leaf = 0x80000002; leaf < 0x80000005; leaf++)
{        
    int regs[4];
    __cpuid(regs, leaf);    
    intbuf[base] = regs[0];     // EAX
    intbuf[base + 1] = regs[1]; // EBX
    intbuf[base + 2] = regs[2]; // ECX
    intbuf[base + 3] = regs[3]; // EDX
    base += 4;
}
```

If you want to keep `intbuf` as an array of `unsigned int`, then you should add a cast to the assignments inside the loop, like:

```cpp
//...
    intbuf[base + 1] = static_cast<unsigned int>(regs[1]); // EBX
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This answer is based on the operation of the [MSVC implementation of the `__cpuid` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/cpuid-cpuidex?view=msvc-170); other compilers' versions may differ *slightly* but the general principle will likely remain the same.

Comment: If the type of `intbuf` was compatible, you could just do `__cpuid(intbuf + base, leaf)`.  But yeah, unfortunately MSVC's `__cpuid` uses an `int[4]` output array.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/cpuid-cpuidex?view=msvc-170 .  They're typically bitfields, it makes much more sense to use `unsigned` with them.  Some leafs do have integer values like cache sizes, though.

Comment: `static_cast<unsigned int>` is overkill.  `__cpuid` is an intrinsic for an x86 / x86-64 instruction, so this code can only run on x86 CPUs. x86 CPUs use 2's complement, so will any sane C++ implementation for them, and conversion from same-width signed to unsigned preserves the bit-pattern. (Also, C++20 standardizes 2's complement and forbids padding bits) So yes this will optimize away whether you write an explicit cast or leave it implicit, or if you use `memcpy`.  But the `static_cast<unsigned int>` seems odd to me, like clutter that makes it less easy to immediately see the `regs[1]` part.

Comment: @Peter I agree that it is 'overkill' in any real, sane world. However, without that (or some other) cast, the MSVC compiler will issue warnings.